# jQuery if Url string exists then add it to another element as href

Tags: jquery

With my CMS, I can create some custom fields for my events. I want to have two custom fields, **Registration Status** and **Registration Url**.

The Registration Status field is multiple choice radio buttons with two values, Register Now and Coming Soon.  And the Registration Url is just a text field to input the registration link.

I can output these two fields in my events but instead of just displaying text, I'd rather to hyperlink the Register Now with the registration Url, but I want this to happen only if the 'Register Now' is selected as status.

Here's what my markup output looks like:

```
<div class="RegStatus">Register Now</div>
<div class="RegUrl">https://www.someRegistrationLink.com</div>
```

And if the status of the event is Coming Soon and the registration link is not provided, then it will look like this:

```
<div class="RegStatus">Coming Soon</div>
<div class="RegUrl"></div>
```

The two elements above can be hidden by CSS and I also have this element that it will be changed by jQuery:

```
<div class="RegBox"><a class="RegButton"></a></div>
```

Now, I have this scenario working with this:

```
var getRegStatus = $('.RegStatus').text();
var getRegUrl = $('.RegUrl').text();

if (getRegStatus === 'Register Now') {
$('.RegBox a.RegButton').text('Register Now').attr('href', getRegUrl);
}
```

It works but it is error prone, like as if a user selects the Register Now status and forgets to provide the Registration Url or vice versa.  Is it possible to make sure both conditions are met before executing the statement?  Something like IF the Status is "Register Now" and IF the Url is provided, then do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace    `if (getRegStatus === 'Register Now')` with
           `if (getRegStatus === 'Register Now' && getRegUrl.length)`